# is Store Kit framework working on i OS 6 Simulator?

Tags: iphone, ios-simulator, in-app-purchase, ios6, xcode4.5

I implemented In App Purchase in my application. It is working fine on iPhone 5.1.

I know Store Kit is not working on iPhone Simulator 5.1. 
But on i OS 6 simulator, i can connect to  App store and i get alert for confirmation In App Purchase. But the transaction is failed with error on iOS 6 Simulator.

Any one please explain reason for this.

Comment: Error Domain=SKErrorDomain Code=0 "Cannot connect to iTunes Store" UserInfo=0xc143420 {NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot connect to iTunes Store}. Even I encountered this error on iPad 6.0 Simulator...

Answer (score 8):

**Simulator**

For this release, iOS Simulator does not support testing In-App Purchase. Please use a device to test your apps that use this feature.

[iOS 6.0 Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/General/RN-iOSSDK-6_0/_index.html)

Answer (score 0):

On Xcode 4.5.2 and iOS 5 and iOS 6 it works fine.
I try in simulators for iPhone 5 and 4, and on all iPads too.
There is only a little delay in the simulator, but the transaction is fully functionally
I see that is very important the configuration in iTunesConnect.
In my opinion is better to check the ItunesConnect config before change the code.

Answer (score 0):

the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/DevelopingwithStoreKit/DevelopingwithStoreKit.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH103-SW3) say that IAP can be fully tested in the sim, except for hosted content: